# Do you need to install Windows on a PC?

Tags: linux, windows, installation

I have bought a new PC intending to use it as Linux box. I specified "No operating system". The BIOS/UEFI won't boot from a Linux ISO and the manufacturer tells me I must load Windows first (see [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1822429/missing-drivers-when-installing-windows-from-a-usb-stick?noredirect=1#comment2868517_1822429)).

Is this right?

I don't have Windows and I don't want it - I certainly don't want to pay.

What options do I have?

Comment: You can't boot anything from an ISO, you need to convert that into a bootable stick first.

Comment: Have you made sure that secure boot is disabled? Might be that they are assuming Windows needs to be installed to set up the keys necessary for secure boot.

Comment: @Tetsujin I might have got the terminology wrong. On other PCs I use a USB stick with the ISO loaded onto it - the BIOS then uses that to boot into Linux

Comment: Does it boot into the USB stick in native UEFI mode or in BIOS-compatibility mode?

Comment: If your USB stick was primarily used for older machines that are booting in BIOS/CSM mode then you may need to recreate it using tools that understand UEFI mode.

Comment: Did you copy the iso to the usb stick or did you write it at a low level?

Comment: @Bib  sudo dd bs=4M if=.... I know it works - have booted 2 other PCs with this USB drive

Comment: Your other question is has a screenshot from the WinPE. Which means you were trying to install Windows. If you don’t want Windows don’t try and install it

Comment: This is a Linux camp problem, unfortunately. New PC means all kinds of security measures, and one of them are keys baked into UEFI, which every bootable medium must have also (simplifying the concept mightily). otherwise UEFI will not recognize that medium. I think as of today there are 2 maybe three distros that are in on these UEFI credentials. There are ways to get around that, but that involves generating own keys and so on, then own UEFI BIOS version and so on... So it may be easier to go WinPE/Windows installers. You don't need Win PK to install a copy, so all you get is some lost time.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm installing windows 'cos my supplier said I needed to - see @ AcePL's comment

Comment: @AcePL "So it may be easier to go WinPE/Windows installers." - can you point me to insstructions for this? Thanks

Comment: @AcePL and the vendors advice sound suspect to me.  Most Linux vendors use a shim (https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot#Shim).  If for some reason this did not work I cant see how installing Windows first would help.   What motherboard/BIOS/UEFI are you using?  Are you sure this is not just a problem with the ordering of the boot loader?

Comment: (shim uses a key signrd by Microsoft so if Windows boots  Linux will too)

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for that I'll look at it tomorrow

Comment: @davidgo motherboard is ASUS ROG Strix B760-F, BIOS/UEFI= ROG STRIX Z790-H ver 1501

Comment: I'd be gobsmacked if you could not get an ASUS ROG board to boot to Linux - its not a no name brand, low volume motherboard - you probably just need to change some BIOS settings.  Looking at 3:23 at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEuOvYVyTtE (assuming your BIOS is similar, once you are in Advanced BIOS settings you have a "BOOT" option with "Secure Boot" settings and boot priorities. Do you see this?  What have you tried here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150433/discussion-between-psionman-and-davidgo).

Comment: @davidgo - I assumed that OP did a minimum configuration in BIOS/UEFI before attempting installation. I guess I should not have. I am now experimenting with modifying UEFI to have it more secure by use of own keys (which is a non-trivial excercise), and this is the bit from which I assert the Microsoft supremacy in UEFI security re: BIOS/MB vendors, but obviously it's at different level and I may have that mixed up. In my defense: I'm old, sick and tired. ;-)

Comment: @AcePL Yeah,  definately a whole other level, and  relying on the company that came up with embrace,extend,extinguish is not a great place to be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You do not need to load Windows.

To summarize:

- First step is to disable Secure boot setting in UEFI.
- Second step is to follow the Linux distribution's installation guide. Always make sure the distribution allows for an UEFI install.

In this SPECIFIC case it was an ASUS ROG STRIX Z790-H GAMING WIFI, so you have to look up the support page or look inside UEFI for how to disable Secure boot.

https://rog.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1049829#AA

Then follow the Manjaro UEFI instructions

https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=UEFI_-_Install_Guide

Comment: Can you please add details from the links so this answer is self-contained?  Thanks!

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate Every distribution and Motherboard behaves differently.
The links don't state what to do in every case, but rather what to do in a specific case and are rather long. It would obfuscate the essence of the answer.
One could maybe remove the links, to make it more self-contained.

Comment: @PatrickAbraham Those are good points.  Maybe the essential points could be summarized while keeping the links?  What do you think?

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate I guess there won't be an update from Psionman, since he answered his own question and in the discussion he stated, that it works for him.

Comment: I think @dave m's edits give a good balance between general and specific. I included my specific links to guide any user wanting a solution, to see what they had to do

Comment: @Psionman not to be mean, but those were my edits. Dave just edited some style and that was enough that it's not my edit any more. Which I find kind of funny and sad at the same time.